# Numerical methods for ODE: Implicit, explicit, stability, stiffness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Hy everybody!

I am new to the subject "numerical methods for ODE". I read some basic literature but since most of the concepts and methods are new to me, I wanted to ask you, if you could give me feedback if I understand everything correctly (if there are wrong statements/definitions, would be great, if you could correct them :)) regarding implict/explicit ODE and stiffness/stability:

Stability: This graphic shows the stability for a specific test function:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/23972/versions/22/previews/chebfun/examples/ode/html/Regions_02.png

Unfortunately, when it comes to stability, it depends on what ODE we want to solve. So there is no general way to say: Is this method stable for this ODE.  So we are creating a so called “model-problem” (see graphic) where we can compare different methods. --> is that correct?

Explicit Runge–Kutta methods are generally unsuitable for solving stiff systems because their region of absolute stability is small. Is there a specific reason why? Could anyone explain it in simple words?

Implicit methods: Have much better stability properties than explicit methods. An explicit method can not be A-stable (everything on the left plane is stable). A-stable methods have no restriction on the step-length, they are very fast! Could anyone explain it in simple words why (some) Implicit methods are A-stable

Implicit methods are more computation intense – but probably you need fewer steps.

Regarding: “no restriction on the step-length”: Does that mean “even if the numeric solution is completely wrong (huge step-length), the system is stable?

Why have multi-step methods advantages compared to single-step methods when it comes to stiff-systems (and stability?)?

Comment: Why do you have two very similar questions?

Comment: First i posted one question - user recommended to split it up.

Comment: Implicit Runge Kutta Methods are A stable, because when applying them to the test equation, the step size $\lambda$ is in the denominator.